# import dyamic formula in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

hello I have some condition in excel :

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2;C3=C2);D2;IF(AND(A3=A2;C3<>C2;B3<1);D2;IF(AND(A3=A2;C3<>C2;B3>=1);D2&","&C3;C3)))
```

I want to write this condition in excel using openpyxl and python .

but I dont know how to define correct previous and next values to do my conditions dynamic to import in my excel.

here the code :

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test1.xlsx')
print wb.get_sheet_names()
Sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet.columns[3], 2):
      current=i
      next=current+1
      previous=current-1
      cellObj.value = '=IF(AND($A${2}=$A${1};$C${2}=$C${1});$D${0};IF(AND($A${2}=$A${1};$C${2}<>$C${1};$B${1}<1);$D${0};IF(AND($A${2}=$A${0};$C${2}<>$C${1};$B${1}>=1);$D${0}&","&$C${2};$C${2})))'.format(previous,current,next)
wb.save('test1.xlsx')
```

but don't work don't show some error but I don't take some result if I try to open excel say me excel is broken.

any idea how to import dynamic formula to excel ?